# Firefox textareas don't scroll to cursor/caret when overflow set to hidden

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want a textarea with no scrollbars. This is done by setting overflow to hidden. However, in Firefox, if I add a new line to the bottom of the textarea, that new line is not visible - the textarea fails to scroll down to the new line. How can I get Firefox to follow the IE/Opera behaviour, whereby if a new line is added, the textarea automatically scrolls down so that it can be seen, whether or not scrollbars are displayed?

Comment: You might want to look at a similar question I posted a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354584/how-to-move-the-textbox-viewport-when-gaining-focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The point of](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) overflow:hidden is to hide the scrollbars and the extra content. If you add a line outside of the limits of the textarea, it is not supposed to display.

You might be able to bypass that with some [javascript](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/). My call would be to rethink your UI, but I don't have all the elements, so maybe I'm wrong about that.

Comment: So are you saying that the FF implementation is correct, and IE and Opera are wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd say that the specs are blurry leaving room for interpretation :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you programmatically adding the new line of text, or is the user typing it?

Either way, you can scroll the textarea to the bottom with a bit of javascript:

```
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
```

scrollHeight is the total height of the content, including the hidden bits.
scrollTop is the offset of the visible area from the top of the content.